# Bind values of matInput to the array its created from

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm setting up a list view of properties from an existing array of items which have variables that will be shown on the page with input-textboxes. Now I want to update the variables of the objects with the value inside the input-textboxes.

To be more precise: I have an object called monitoring which has a list of pattern objects. These pattern objects have variables which will be listed in the view with input-textboxes where we can change the values. If the values in the input-boxes are changed, I want to update the corresponding pattern objects' variables with these values.

The html looks like this:

```
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-list>
      <div *ngFor="let pattern of monitoring?.patterns" class="pattern-instance-item">
        <mat-list-item>
          <div class="pattern-name">
            Name: {{pattern.name}}
          </div>
          <mat-form-field *ngFor="let variable of pattern.variables" class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput [placeholder]="variable.key" [value]="variable.value">
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-button (click)="deletePatternInstance(pattern, variable)">
             <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-button (click)="updateMonitoringArea(pattern, variable)">
            <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </div>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-card-content>
```

I have a backend server based on spring where the monitoring objects should have the patterns with the variable values that are specified in the frontend.

Comment: You can use form control for the same and print value of it or you can use ngModel instead of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`[(ngModel)]="variable.value"`** to bind the `input` tag value.
Remember to give each `input` tag a unique name, here i am assigning index value.

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let variable of pattern.variables; ;let index = index;" 
    class="example-full-width">
            <input name={{index}} [(ngModel)]="variable.value" matInput 
            [placeholder]="variable.key" [value]="variable.value">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: So how can I get this values in my component.ts using the index? Do I have to pass each one of them to a method or can I get them collectively as a list and pass it to the component.ts method?

Comment: No, it will update the new `input` tag value into `variable.value`. And whenever you need the updated input tag value, you can find from `variable.value`. Refer: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: @A.Ka. Glad, i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use formControl or ngModel for the matInput as below:
Html:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let variable of pattern.variables" class="example-full-width">           
      <input matInput [placeholder]="variable.key" formControlName="variableName" 
      [value]="variable.value">        
  </mat-form-field>

Ts:

options: FormGroup;
   this.options = fb.group({
       variableName: ''
   });
```

Comment: This is yet another approach that works fine. Thanks!